# How do I attach an HTML file using Outlook 2010 command line switches without the file getting embedded in the email itself?

Tags: html, windows, outlook, cmd

This is the command I'm using:

```
outlook.exe /c ipm.note /m sample@sample.com /a "E:\output.html"
```

However, when I do this, the HTML file gets embedded in the email.
How do I attach it separately?

(I'm using Microsoft Outlook 2010.)